# 'ls -l' file timestamp format

Tags: ls, locale

When I issue the command:

```
ls -l
```

The file/directory modification timestamp column (specifically the month part) is displayed in the native language of the country I'm based in instead of English.

How can I force `ls` to use another 'culture' in that column?

Example:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the locale environment variables such as `LANG` or `LC_ALL`:

```
LANG=C ls -l
```

This way only the current `ls` instance uses another locale. You can also change it for the whole session:

```
export LANG=C
ls -l
```

Read `man 7 locale` for details. Use `locale -a` to list the possible locales you can choose from.

Answer (score 2):

The date format is determined by the locale setting `LC_TIME`. If `LC_TIME` is not set, the default setting `LANG` applies. Also, if you have `LC_ALL` set, it trumps all other settings, and if you have `LANGUAGE` set, it trumps even `LC_ALL`.

In your `.profile`, or other file where you set environment variables, change the locale settings as you desire. If you want default English settings, unset all the locale variables except `LC_CTYPE` which indicates the character set. For example, to use English everywhere and the UTF-8 character set, you can put this in your `~/.profile`:

```
unset LANG LC_ALL LANGUAGE
unset LC_COLLATE LC_MESSAGES LC_MONETARY LC_NUMERIC LC_TIME
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
```